# Prove that the user is the owner before a backend call

Tags: wallet

Is there any way to verify that the logged-in user is the owner of this account? There is an API route to fetch data from this wallet, but I would like to add a security layer so that not just anyone can fetch a lambda wallet. For example MagicEden asks us to "sign in" to get notifications etc.. How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the signMessage function from the wallet adapter package in order to ask the user to sign and confirm the wallet address ownership