# Restrict access by public key with wallet adapter

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm trying to figure out how to restrict which public keys can log in with the wallet adapter. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Ultimately what I'm looking for is something like next-auth callbacks where I can just compare the current pubkey against a list of whitelisted ones and return true if it exists. Anything that works... I guess works, but that's basically how I implemented it with next-auth.

fwiw, my app was created with this project: https://github.com/solana-developers/create-solana-dapp, but I'm only using the frontend of it at this moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the user is the owner before a backend call](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5331/prove-that-the-user-is-the-owner-before-a-backend-call)

Comment: @steveluscher Thanks, that seems like it should work... however I'm having a hard time finding docs on this stuff. Even the wallet adapter repo just has some sample code and that's it. This is the best I can find: https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/interfaces/_solana_wallet_adapter_base.MessageSignerWalletAdapterProps.html#signMessage